# Help with drawing a picture (pgf/tikz)

Tags: diagrams

I am interested on drawing (I suspect that using pgf/tikz is one of the easiest ways to accomplish this) a picture like the following one
[image]

It is supposed to be a grid of the plane (I only care about the points with natural coordinates), where there are some "red bags" which contain some of these points , and there is a region that is coloured on yellow (one of the red bags corresponds exactly to the points in the yellow region).

Any idea about how to use pgf/tikz to draw something like this?

Comment: Why dont you use a drawing program such as [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) or [LibreOffice Draw](http://www.libreoffice.org/) rather then spending hours programming something?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). It would be helpful to show what you have tried so far, and what exactly you are having issues with. For instance, have you been able to draw the grid?

Comment: Indeed to start looking at the manual on my own I would like to know which is the right command to use for the grid, and which is the one to use for the bags.

Comment: @boumol: You can draw the grid using `\draw (0,0) grid (3.5,3.5);`, for example. For drawing the "bags", you can use `\draw [rounded corners=0.2cm] (<coordinate>) -- (<coordinate>) -- <and so on>;`.

Comment: @Jake: What about the colored region?

Comment: @boumol: `\draw [fill] ...`, or just `\fill` if you don't want an outline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am just expanding @Jake's comments into an answer.

```
\documentclass[border=.1cm]{standalone} %change to article or whatever...
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \fill [green!80!blue] (3.5,0) -- (3,0) -- (3,1) -- (2,1) -- (2,2) -- (1,2) -- (1,3.5) -- (3.5,3.5) -- cycle;
\draw[thin] (0,0) grid (4.5,4.5);
\draw[brown,ultra thick] (0,0) circle (0.3cm);
\draw [rounded corners=0.2cm,brown,very thick] (1.2,-0.4) -- (1.2,1.3) -- (0.8,1.3) -- (0.8,-0.4) -- cycle;
\draw[brown,ultra thick] (2,0) circle (0.3cm);
\draw [rounded corners=0.2cm,brown,very thick]  (0.2,4.3) --  (0.2,0.8) --  (-0.2,0.8) -- (-0.2,4.3);
\foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,4}
\foreach \y in {,0,1,2,3,4}
{
\draw[fill=black] (\x,\y) circle (1pt);
}
% \fill [green!80!blue,opacity=.4] (3.5,0) -- (3,0) -- (3,1) -- (2,1) -- (2,2) -- (1,2) -- (1,3.5) -- (3.5,3.5) -- cycle;
\draw [rounded corners=0.2cm,brown,very thick]  (4.3,-0.3) --  (2.8,-0.3) --  (2.8,0.8) -- (1.8,0.8) -- (1.8,1.8) -- (0.8,1.8) -- (0.8,4.3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of putting

```
\fill [green!80!blue] (3.5,0) -- (3,0) -- (3,1) -- (2,1) -- (2,2) -- (1,2) -- (1,3.5) -- (3.5,3.5) -- cycle;
```

in the beginning you can put it anywhere and use `opacity = .4` ( or any value as you like) as:

```
\fill [green!80!blue,opacity=.4] (3.5,0) -- (3,0) -- (3,1) -- (2,1) -- (2,2) -- (1,2) -- (1,3.5) -- (3.5,3.5) -- cycle;
```

to get

[image]

Pl. note that I have used a very conventional and simple way of putting coordinates. Things can be made more complex and neat.